# How to use internal links in sanity.io and gatsby with gatsby-source-sanity?

Tags: gatsby, sanity

I have created an internalLink type following the sanity documentation and as per the gotcha note about using internalLinks with a graphql api, I have created it as a separate type as follows:

```
export default {
    name: 'internalLink',
    type: 'object',
    title: 'Internal link',
    fields: [
      {
        name: 'reference',
        type: 'reference',
        title: 'Reference',
        to: [
          { type: 'helpTopic' },
          // other types you may want to link to
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have added it schema.js as follows:

```
import internalLink from './internalLink'

export default createSchema({
  name: 'default',
  types: schemaTypes.concat([
    internalLink,
    helpTopic,
    blockContent,
    figure,
    slideshow,
  ])
})
```

and added it to annotations as follows:

```
annotations: [
          {
            type: 'internalLink'
          }
        ]
```

When I use graphiql in Gatsby, if I do not use resolveReferences, then I get the unresolved references properly:

```
"markDefs": [
                {
                  "_key": "00a07e239d3d",
                  "_type": "internalLink",
                  "reference": {
                    "_ref": "7c635eee-0d98-5335-a376-4101922ca4b7",
                    "_type": "reference"
                  }
                }
              ]
```

however, when I use `_rawBody(resolveReferences:{maxDepth:1000})`, the reference does not get resolved and returns as null:

```
"markDefs": [
                {
                  "_key": "00a07e239d3d",
                  "_type": "internalLink",
                  "reference": null
                }
              ]
```

Is this a bug or is there something wrong that I am doing. I have tried going through the docs but cannot figure this out and the example gatsby sanity combo project does not have an internalLinks example.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Did you deploy the GraphQL endpoint after you changed the schema? You will have to run `sanity graphql deploy` every time you change the schema. There might be some mismatch making it result into `null`. Just want to make sure that before delving into this deeper.

Comment: Yes, I did run `sanity graphql deploy` and I checked in the playground as well that it does have the reference property with the correct ID. It's just the resolve references that seems to be giving me the error. Thanks for replying, hope you can give any insights into what may be the error.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to find a way?

Comment: I posted an issue on the github page for gatsby-source-sanity and they have replied about a potential fix in a beta release (https://github.com/sanity-io/gatsby-source-sanity/issues/60). I have been sidetracked with other projects so have not had a chance to check yet, but please try out `gatsby-source-sanity@6.0.0-beta.0` and provide feedback to them if it is important to you

Answer (score 2):

As of now annotations cannot accept schema types like that. You will have to put the entire schema block in there. A bit of a weird limitation. I think someone already put in a ticket/feature request regarding this issue on Sanity.io's Github repo.

Comment: Thanks Sharon. However, I actually did it that way first - put the entire schema block in the annotation as an anonymous type. Got the same issue though. Then I followed this link in the sanity docs (https://www.sanity.io/docs/configuration) and tried it with the schema type as I have shown above. Note from docs: "If you plan to use Sanity’s GraphQL API, you should hoist internalLink as a schema type, and use type: 'internalLink' as the annotation instead of the anonymous object in the example above."